# Buttons replacing navigation bar items

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uinavigationbarappearance

I want to get two buttons under status bar:
[image]

First, I hided navigationBar:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

and made 2 buttons on the place of NavigationBar. It worked on simulator, but on real device (iPhone 6) touch event didn't work when the buttons were in navigationBar area

I decided to make custom NavigationBar with transparent background and 2 buttons (one instead back btn and second as a rightView)

I tried instructions from Apple doc:

```
    let backButtonBackgroundImage = UIImage(named: "testDpng.png")
    let barAppearance =
        UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [SubViewController.self])
    barAppearance.backIndicatorImage = backButtonBackgroundImage
    barAppearance.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backButtonBackgroundImage

    // Nudge the back UIBarButtonItem image down a bit.
    let barButtonAppearance =
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [SubViewController.self])
    barButtonAppearance.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -5), for: .default)
```

But nothing happened. The backBtn looks as usual.

How can I fix it? Is it correct way - replace navigation items? Or I should hide navigation bar as I tried from the beginning?

Comment: if you hided your navbar ? then why not have UIView to add buttons ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't hide navigationBar, Make it transparent and add `UIBarButtonItem` to left and right side of navigationBar.

**Below code working for Swift 5 :**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Make NavigationBar Transparent
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

        //Add Left Button Which Has Image
                let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "shape"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(crossBtnTapped))
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = leftButton

        //Add Right Button Which Has Title
                let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Restore", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(restoreTapped))
                rightButton.tintColor = .darkGray
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
}
```

Action methods on buttons tap

```
@objc func restoreTapped(){
     print("Restore Tapped")
}

@objc func crossBtnTapped(){
     print("Cross Tapped")
}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: It helped, but I got the dagger not in the left side of the screen. It seems invisible back button is an obstacle